# Updating PyQt progressbar based on printed stdout from imported package (PyQt5)

Tags: multithreading, pyqt, thread-safety, pyqt5

I'm relatively new to PyQt5 and would appreciate any guidance in achieving the following please.

I'm building a GUI to work on top of a Python package that runs various slow processing tools. The current interface is purely textual: the package runs some code in a loop and prints the current progress percentage completion to the terminal.

My aim is to build a PyQt GUI that displays this progress as a progressbar instead. This could be done simply using QProgressBar.setValue() if I could add this call to the original processing code, but this is not possible; instead, my GUI is to be built on top of the current text output interface from the processing code.

I feel like this should be possible using a thread somehow, but am not sure how to intercept the call to stdout without impeding performance / introducing thread-unsafe operations.

Is this possible? Any suggestions would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote some StackOverflow documentation on this. I'll be writing some more advanced examples soon when I get the time.

[Introduction to Progress Bars in PyQt5](https://medium.com/@taven/pyqt5-progress-bar-1-816c97b15437)

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**:

Due to sunsetting of stack overflow documentation, I've moved the guide to my blog.